# What did Agent Smith mean in saying "no one would accept the programming"?

Tags: the-matrix

I am currently rewatching the Matrix in its entirety and when Agent Smith's monologue in the first film to a captive Morpheus came about a big question arose in my head. When discussing the history of the Matrix's iterations, Agent Smith says:

> Did you know that the first Matrix was designed to be a perfect human world. Where none suffered. Where everyone would be happy. It was a disaster. **No one would accept the program.**

Who is Agent Smith referring to? Is he referring to the Architect and the Oracle at a disagreement? Is he referring to a unseen hierarchy of machines in the real world? Were all the humans **aware they were in a simulation?** I ask because his monologue seems to give the emphasis on the third option:

> Some believed that we lacked the programming language to describe your perfect world. But I believe that as a species, human beings define their reality through misery and suffering. The perfect world was a dream that your primitive cerebrum kept trying to wake up from.

Also who is Smith referring to in the first sentence of the excerpt above?

Comment: You've kind of self-answered here with your second excerpt. The "who" is "the machines".

Answer (score 7):

When Smith said "no one would accept the program", he was clearly referring to the human subjects plugged into the Matrix, since he explained that "entire crops" were lost, and that people kept trying to wake up from the 'perfect world' simulation, forcing the machines to redesign it to make it more like the imperfect, *real world* civilisation that humans had previously lived in.

> SMITH: Did you know that the first Matrix was designed to be a perfect human world. Where none suffered. Where everyone would be happy. It was a disaster. **No one would accept the program. Entire crops were lost.** Some believed that we lacked the programming language to describe your perfect world. But I believe that as a species, human beings define their reality through misery and suffering. **The perfect world was a dream that your primitive cerebrum kept trying to wake up from. Which is why the Matrix was redesigned to this, the peak of your civilization.**
>
> <sub>*The Matrix (1999)*</sub>

The Architect reiterated this in the second film, when he explained that humans wouldn't accept either of the first *two* versions of the Matrix, and that the solution was stumbled upon by the Oracle.

> THE ARCHITECT: **The first Matrix I designed was quite naturally perfect, it was a work of art – flawless, sublime. A triumph equalled only by its monumental failure. The inevitability of its doom is apparent to me now as a consequence of the imperfection inherent in every human being.** Thus, I redesigned it based on your history to more accurately reflect the varying grotesqueries of your nature. However, I was again frustrated by failure. I have since come to understand that the answer eluded me because it required a lesser mind, or perhaps a mind less bound by the parameters of perfection. Thus **the answer was stumbled upon by another – an intuitive program, initially created to investigate certain aspects of the human psyche. If I am the father of the Matrix, she would undoubtedly be its mother.**
>
> NEO: **The Oracle.**
>
> THE ARCHITECT: **Please. As I was saying, she stumbled upon a solution whereby nearly 99% of all test subjects accepted the program, as long as they were given a choice, even if they were only aware of the choice at a near unconscious level.**
>
> <sub>*The Matrix Reloaded (2003)*</sub>

As regards the line "some believed that we lacked the programming language to describe your perfect world", Smith was almost certainly referring to the programs here. There's no suggestion anywhere in the franchise that the machines consulted humans whilst attempting to get the first version of the Matrix to work. Such a scenario seems highly improbable, given what we know about the extremely frosty relationship that existed between humans and the machines at that point in the story.

Since we can reasonably eliminate humans from consideration here, the only remaining alternative is that the machines/programs were discussing these problems among themselves.